# Why aren't my shell script loops working in Linux?

Tags: linux, loops, shell, if-statement

Can anyone help me understand why this is not working? Could anyone even point me in the right direction to learn how to do?

```
x=0
while [ $x = 0 ]
do
        echo “times tables” 
        echo "please select"
        echo "1) addition"
        echo "2) subtraction"
        echo "3) multiply"
        echo "4) division"
        echo "5) exponent"
        read  symbol

case "$symbol" in
        addition)
        echo "enter the number you wish"
        read a
        for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))
        do
        b=$((a +i))
        echo "$a+$i=$b"
        sleep 2
         x=0
echo try another “yes or no”
read answer
if $yes 
x = 0
if $no 
x=


case "$symbol" in
       subtraction)
echo "enter the number you want"
        read a
        for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))
        do
        b=$((a -i))
        echo "$a-$i=$b"
```

I'm basically trying to make a program where the user selects there symbol and then is able to do times tables with that. However, i want it to loop back to the selection of symbols when finished or have another loop inside that lets them continue with the one they are on. When i have them seperated it appears to work. As in if i just remove the option of asking for what symbol and instead just provided addition and a user input for a number, the addition times table will work. Then i can move to subtraction. However, once i try to add a loop. it stops.

Comment: From the top p my head the condition of the while instead of the = sign use -eq or don't use spaces, so $x=0

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Use ‘select’ in bash

Comment: Make a short example which has the same problem. Your current code is missing keywords like `then`, `esac`, `fi` and `done`. Or better: start with a small script and only add lines when the small script is working.

Comment: @sleepyhead `$x=0` would be wrong. `=` isn't necessarily wrong, either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x=0
while [ $x = 0 ]
do
  echo “times tables”
  echo "please select"
  echo "1) addition"
  echo "2) subtraction"
  echo "3) multiply"
  echo "4) division"
  echo "5) exponent"
  read  symbol

  case "$symbol" in
    1)
      echo "enter the number you wish"
      read a
      for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))
      do
        b=$((a + i))
      done
      echo "$a+$i=$b"
      sleep 2
      x=0
    ;;
    2) echo "not implemented" ;;
    3) echo "not implemented" ;;
    4) echo "not implemented" ;;
    5) echo "not implemented" ;;
    *) echo "not implemented" ;;
  esac

  echo try another “yes or no”
  read answer

  if [ "$answer" == "yes" ]
    then {
      x = 0
      echo "[ choose an option ]"
    }
    else {
      echo "exiting..."
      break
    }
  fi
done
```